# Why add ‘now’ in the end of the sentence？

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I see this sentence in a book: “I’ve been coming up here night after night for weeks now.”

I just feel this “now” in the end is weird. May you tell me why the author did this？

Answer (score 2):

Not weird. Normal. 'Night after night' is used to emphasise that the speaker has been coming repeatedly (and is possibly tired of doing that). One of the uses of 'now' is to express that something has been happening for a period of time up to the present.

> Now
>
> adverb
>
> used to express how long something has been happening, from when it
> began to the present time:
>
> *She's been a vegetarian for ten years now.*

[Now (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/now)